# AutoComplete for Asp.net C# Not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax, web-services

I have tried everything. I am trying to get autocomplete to work for an input textbox and I can't get it to work. I am implementing it into a DNN webpage here is the code I am using for this autocomplete...

I keep getting error every time.

I am welcome to do a teamviewer session.

Thank you.

ASP.NET code

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlInfoSearch" runat="server">
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "View.ascx/GetPartNumber",
                    data: "{'PartNumber':'" + document.getElementById('txtPartNum').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>


<div id="introcopy">
    <h2>Product Info Center</h2>
    <p>Download technical and quality documents, check inventory and order samples for your parts.</p>
</div> 
<div class="demo">
    <p>Enter a part number (or portion of a part number) to retrieve information about that product.</p>
    <input type="text" id="txtPartNum" value="Enter part #..." style="height: 18px" class="autosuggest" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    var _sDefaultText = 'Enter part #...';
    jQuery('#txtPartNum').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = '<%= new Uri(String.Concat("http://", Page.Request.UserHostName, Page.Request.RawUrl)).AbsolutePath %>?partnum=' + jQuery(this).val();
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val() === _sDefaultText) {
            jQuery(this).val('');
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val().length == 0) {
            jQuery(this).val(_sDefaultText);
        }
    });
// ]]>
</script>

<br class="clear" />
</asp:Panel>
```

C# code....

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetPartNumber(string PartNumber)
{
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("HIDDEN"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PartNumber from Products.Products where PartNumber LIKE @SearchText+'%'", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", PartNumber);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["PartNumber"].ToString());
                }

                return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you are claiming to have problem with autocomplete but have SQL code as sample of data source for autocomplete instead of hardcoded data - please make sure you know where "getting error every time" comes from and what these errors say exactly. Also make sure to edit tags to include proper jQuery once.

Comment: In other words, post the error!

Answer (score 1):

If you think your issue is SQL related, then refactor the SQL related code and write some tests against that method with some know part numbers.

Looking at your code, the URL for your service method stands out. You specify You specified `url: "View.ascx/GetPartNumber"` but I would assume you either meant something else (maybe View.ashx or View.asmx). Are you able to hit your service method via your browser as a simple GET?

What do you get when you access this URI in your browser? `/View.ascx/GetPartNumber?PartNumber=xyz`